# 'who is' or 'who are', when the sentence subject is 'you'

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Here's a sentence:

> Are you a parent *and is* looking for answers on [something]?

My proposed corrections:

> 1. Are you a parent *and are* looking for answers on [something]?
> 2. Are you a parent *who is* looking for answers on [something]? *

My friend argues about the **second** correction, saying it is incorrect and it should be:

> Are you a parent *who are* looking for answers on [something]? ^

Who is right, and **why?**

* Justification for *who is*: The pronoun *who* refers to *a parent*, not *you*.
^ Justification for *who are*: The subject of the sentence is *you*, not *a parent*, hence the verb *to be* that comes after *who* must agree with the subject, *you*.

Comment: I would write "Are you a parent looking for answers on [...]?" and avoid the full issue. :)

Comment: Your friend is wrong.  No one talks like that.

Comment: @WendiKidd Thanks for the edit. I didn't mean to offend anyone :)

Comment: @ADTC In this case, you could say "in Standard English", since that's what your question is focusing on (and what we generally try to focus on here at ELL).  If you need a more neutral way to refer to the dialect you mentioned, try AAVE (African American Vernacular English).  In particular, I suggest leaving out the "thug" part, since it's spoken widely by non-thugs.

Comment: Er, that was just a quote, extraneous information.. and yes, I'm looking for standard English answers.. I probably, shouldn't have included the quote, that was a bad idea (thought it's funny, but I guess some may not take it lightly).. anyway, the question is not about AAVE or thugs. Besides it's already edited out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking on the *Corpus of Contemporary American English* for sentences containing *are you a [noun] who* I find only sentences like the second one you wrote.

> Are you a person who's a long time here?

> Are you a poet who's a doctor, or are you a doctor who's a poet?

> Is that who you are, or are you a Christian who sings?

The reason is the one you said: The noun phrase requires a verb in the third singular person. It is "a doctor who is a poet" not "a doctor who are poet." You could say "doctors who are poets," but that would mean that the subject of the sentence is plural.

> Are you parents who are looking for answers on [...]?

You can also not use "who is" / "who are."

> Are you a parent looking for answers on [...]?

In this case, you would be using a [present participle phrase](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/participlephrase.htm) that, as all the participle phrases, acts as adjective.

Comment: I don't think you've clearly identified that your first example sentence ("Are you a person who's a long time here?") is incorrect. I don't want to change your answer in a way you wouldn't want, so would you mind editing to remedy this? I could try if you prefer, but I wanted to give you the option first. (And I'll delete this comment once we've sorted it out, so it doesn't clutter up your answer :))  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Something however is wrong with your first example as Wendi points out. I would also like you to expand contractions (who's -> who is) so that the examples are explicitly clear.

Comment: What's wrong with the first example sentence is the verb tense. It should be "Are you a person who has been a long time here" (or more idiomatically, "Are you a person who's been here a long time").

Comment: @WendiKidd The sentences I wrote have been taken from the _Corpus of Contemporary American English_. They are not examples I wrote myself.

Comment: The sentence in question *is* in COCA, but it ultimately comes from [this article in *The Atlantic*](http://www.theatlantic.com/past/docs/issues/98nov/lovely.htm).  It's a transcription of an old woman's spoken English, and I don't think it was intended to represent Standard English.  I think that perhaps it's dialect, though I can't identify which one.  (Perhaps another user such as @StoneyB might recognize it...?)

Comment: @snailboat Nice research there! I'm a bit confused about how it could be a dialect; I seem to be missing a verb. (Are you a person who is *what*?) And if only that ping would work, we could ask him! Perhaps that's a new feature request: opt in to let people ping you anywhere? ;)

Comment: @WendiKidd If not, then maybe it's a mistake.  I don't know which!