# Who have or who has in a question

Tags: grammar

I want to to ask a question, but I do not know the right one in the following two questions:
- Who have agreed on that with you?
- Who has agreed on that with you?

Comment: possible duplicate of ['who is' or 'who are', when the sentence subject is 'you'](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7904/who-is-or-who-are-when-the-sentence-subject-is-you)

Comment: *Who* in the linked question is referential, but this *who* is non-referential.  This makes the answers different and the questions non-duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

That simply depends on what you want to ask:

> Who **are** the people who agreed on that with you?
>   Who **have** agreed?
>
> Who **is** the person who agreed on that with you?
>   Who **has** agreed?

If you do not know whether this agreement was between two people (the one you are asking and one other) or between more people, the way of asking it, is in the singular:

> Who **has** agreed with you on that?

Comment: ... Which is not taken to make the answer 'Ali, Jill and John' ungrammatical.

Comment: I can't think of *any* situation where asking a question starting with "Who have..." is correct. It's "Who has..." every time.

Comment: @toandfro: Who have won the derby? City or United?

Comment: @oerkelens Eh? That's just wrong. *Who has won the derby?* is the right way to ask that question.

Comment: Unless you refer to the team. It is very normal in BrE to refer to a team notionally in the plural: Man United _have_ won their game.

Comment: The example in your question needs to use *has*, too.

Comment: @oerkelens I agree that collective nouns may be treated as singular or plural, but that is not the issue here. *Who have* is quite simply wrong, and the example you have inserted into your answer is wrong, as snailplane has pointed out. I don't understand why you are defending it.

Comment: Well, I am not completely convinced that there is _no_ situation where the plural _could_ be correct, but I will accept my example was not correct :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend removing *has/have* altogether leaving:

> Who agreed with you on that?